# How to click on an element which is visible=false in an ios mobile app

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automation, appium

I have to automate an iOS pega mobile app, there I have a field which i need to click. But that field in set to visible "false". Is there a way where i can click on that element?

[Image of the mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72oVB.png)

1. Approach (1) I used
   Click on the Time(secs) text field, but this is set to visible false

`String selector = "type=='XCUIElementTypeStaticText' AND rect.x==101 AND rect.y==150 AND(visible == 0 OR enabled == 1)";
        MobileElement timeEle = driver.findElementByIosNsPredicate(selector);
        timeEle.click();`

2. Approach (2) I used
   Click on the "Clock" icon, even for that i used predicate string still it's not working.

xpath shown in Appium,

```
//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="Center Panel, region"]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[4]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[3]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with hidden elements, you'll typically want to use javascript to interact with them.

In java, and with your example, this would look like

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor; # added to the top of the script
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", timeEle);
```

Comment: The issue is i cannot find the element to click. It gives me an error saying "Got an unexpected response with status 404: {"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"unable to find an element using 'predicate string', value 'type=='XCUIElementTypeTextField' AND rect.x==25 AND rect.y==164 AND(visible == 0 OR enabled == 1)'"

Comment: Are you able to use an inspector to check the element tag, class, name, or something else to identify it?

Comment: yeah, from appium i'm inspecting it.